# error during launch of svn command in aix machine

Tags: svn, aix

Hi I'm using `aix` machine for some development work.Svn is installed in my machine but it's giving error when using it.
If I run *svn --version command*, it's giving the below error:

```
/home/vpmadm>svn --version
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program svn because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module /usr/ora10g2/lib/libexpat.so could not be loaded.
        0509-103   The module has an invalid magic number.
```

Can you please check it out and let me know any possible solution.

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score -1):

Try `unset LIBPATH` and then perform your **SVN** commands as desired.